# Search Query Parser

Tags: php, parsing, search

My App is supposed to search the stored Images based on the search Query. The User can search in `label`, `description`, `people tagged in`, `time posted` . for that I am trying to make a Search Query `parser` that accepts `wild card (*)` `@TaggedPeopleName` `(DateFrom - DateTo)` `#Place` and all other texts to match label and description. My question is am I reinventing the wheel ? or there already exists such parser may be with similar functionality ?

Example Queries are:

- `@JohnLenon 500 Miles`

  will return the Images that Match `500 Miles` in Label or in description and has a Tag of John Lenon
- `(24 Dec - 30 Dec)`

  will return all Images uploaded in that time Frame.
- `#Kolkata (24 dec - 31 Dec) Occupy Together`

  will return all Images that Match the String `Occupy Together` in Label or in description and withing the Time Frame `24 dec to 31 Dec` and Taken at the Place `Kolkata`

If some Library already does this may be with different syntax I'll accept. as I am not sticked to this syntax only

Comment: Add some example queries to your question, which I think will make more clear what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is nothing that does this automatically for you - it's way too particular to your situation.

I would break it down in chunks to make it easy.

Search for all terms starting with @ - remove them.
Search for all terms starting with # - remove them.
Search for all terms surrounded by () - remove them.
What's left is the general search term.

Things to think about:

- What if someone wants to search for a term in a description that starts with @ or #?
- What is the format of the () terms - most people won't naturally format dates as you have?
- What if someone just puts in junk between the ()?
- What if two words are separated by another token, but after removing them are put together?
- Or what if the person puts two words together but doesn't want them searched for as one term?